# Phantomjs Automation of a website leads me to getting IP blocked

Tags: phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to automate a page. What I do is:

```
    do{
    console.log(i);
    i++;

    page.open(url);
    do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.loading);

    if(page.injectJs('./Search.js') == false){
        console.log("Search.js Failed")
    }

    var links = page.evaluate(function(json){
        return search(json)
    },json)
    console.log(links);

} while(links == "")
```

So this leads me to opening the website repeated until what I'm looking for appears. But this also leads me to getting IP banned. What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IP is probably getting banned because the script generates too many requests to the website in very little time. So, you need to throttle requests, to apply a pause between them.

I would rewrite your script like this:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "http://www.website.tld/";
var json = {"some" : "json"};
var i = 0;
var links;

// We abstract main code to a function so that we can call it 
// again and again from itself
function getlinks (url, json) {

    i++;
    console.log(i);

    page.open(url);
    do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.loading);

    if(page.injectJs('./Search.js') == false){
        console.log("Search.js Failed")
    }

    var links = page.evaluate(function(json){
        return search(json);
    }, json);

    if(links == "")
    {
        // No links scraped yet, so we wait for 3 seconds and try again
        setTimeout(function(){
            getlinks(url, json);
        }, 3000)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(links);
        phantom.exit();
    }
}

getlinks(url, json);
```